# How to execute parallel processes based on conditional with RxJava2

Tags: android, parallel-processing, rx-java2

I am attempting to employ RxJava2 in my current Android project.

```
   implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
   implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.12'
```

I have a number of use cases that follow this pattern.

```
1). Check a condition is true or false.
2). When condition is true
2.1). Execute multiple processes in parallel
2.2). wait until all parallel process have completed.
3). When condition is false.
3.1). Do nothing.
```

One such use case is I check if my local database requires refreshing from a remote source.

I have got this far and now I am stuck...

```
 refreshRequired().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(getObserver());
```

the methods in question resemble this:-

```
/**
 *
 * @return
 */
private Single<Boolean> refreshRequired() {
    return Single.create(new SingleOnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(final SingleEmitter<Boolean> emitter) {
            if (emitter.isDisposed()) {

            } else {
                emitter.onSuccess(isRefreshRequired());
            }
        }
    });

}

/**
 *
 * @return
 */
private SingleObserver<Boolean> getObserver() {
    return new SingleObserver<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(final Disposable disposable) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final Boolean value) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess() called with: value = [" + value + "]");

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(final Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onError() called with: ", throwable);
        }
    };
}
```

What I cannot understand is how to trigger my parallel process when the `public void onSuccess(final Boolean value) {}` method receives a value of `true`

the pseudo code of this process would be:-

```
When refreshRequired
  Refresh Data A
  Refresh Data B
  Refresh Data C
  Stop
Otherwise
  Stop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by splitting the reactive stream in two by using the `filter` operator:

```
Observable<Boolean> refreshRequiredObservable = refreshRequired();

refreshRequiredObservable.filter(refreshRequired -> refreshRequired)
        .doOnNext(aBoolean -> System.out.println("Do first thing"))
        .doOnNext(aBoolean -> System.out.println("Do second thing"))
        .doOnNext(aBoolean -> System.out.println("Do third thing"))
        .subscribe();

refreshRequiredObservable.filter(refreshRequired -> !refreshRequired)
        .doOnNext(aBoolean -> System.out.println("Do nothing"))
        .subscribe();
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to resolve my issue. I now have a further requirement: When all the "doNext(aBoolean..." have completed OK I need to execute a "trailer" process, I've tried "doFinally()" and "doAfterTerminate()" and neither approach executes at the correct time. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: That depends on what kind of methods are you calling in the doOnNext - are they synchronous or asynchronous? If it's the latter then you should use flatMap/concatMap instead of doOnNext.